# Why do we run `ssh-agent` with `eval`?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

What is the purpose we run `ssh-agent` with

```
eval `ssh-agent`
```

not just

```
ssh-agent
```

?

Comment: Take a look at the output of `ssh_agent`. It's just output, and it doesn't change anything. In order for it to change something you need to execute the result, hence `eval`. Is that answering what you're asking?

Comment: @roaima ah, yes, I am an idiot, thanks :D

Comment: I don't see anything here that suggests you're an idiot. It was a reasonable question. (I'm now waiting for you to ask the follow-on, which is why `ssh-agent` can't make the changes itself... :-)

Comment: What the linked question doesn't explicitly explain is the point is to set environment for future processes spawned from an already running shell. `ssh-agent` process can only change its own environment or set environment for its child. There is no other way for it to change the environment of the current *shell* than to print commands and let the shell evaluate them.

Comment: @roaima I confused two evaluations, one with quotes, another with `eval` command, it was real thinking mistake